# How to get Count from Subquery when main query returns no records

Tags: mysql, count, subquery

The MYSQL query below gives me the output I need when there are records found in the main query e.g.

RETURN:

```
username  |  total_favs
this_user |  4
```

But I get nothing return if no records found in main query. I want to get something like this:

RETURN:

```
username  |  total_favs
null |  4

SELECT 
  c.username,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_records FROM favourites f WHERE f.pic_id = 177) AS `total_favs`
FROM
  comments c
WHERE
  c.pic_id = 177
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switch it around so `favourites` is the main query:

```
SELECT c.username, COUNT(*) AS total_favs
FROM favourites f
LEFT OUTER JOIN comments c on f.pic_id = c.pic_id
WHERE f.pic_id = 177
GROUP BY c.username
```

Comment: That does work fine if there are no records found in table 'comments' but if there are records in table 'comments' but none in table 'favourites' I get no results again. I'd like to get results if either table returns nothing. e.g.
username  |  total_favs
this_user |  NULL

Comment: Would the "WHERE NOT EXISTS" be helpful?

Comment: @PaulBenbow Your two queries aren't really related then... Maybe you're better off just running two queries.

Comment: I think you're probably right. Was trying to maximise performance by using 1 query. It could probably be done with a Stored Procedure and IF THEN but two simple queries may be quicker.

Comment: @PaulBenbow Again, I don't know what your data looks like. But you also need to define what you want to happen when there's more than one row in `comments` for a given `pic_id`.